# Smart proxy providing filtered view on CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I thought I had found the holy grail when I stumbled over [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/), a while ago; it allowed me to simply write my code to a local (in-browser) database, and then replicate everything to and from a remote CouchDB without actually having to write a single line of code. (Not entirely true, it is actually a single line of code.)

However, if I use CouchDB as the backend, all users will actually get exactly the same view of the data. That's not all that desirable. I am making an application for different groups of people, and they shouldn't be able to see each others data. Never. Period.

In fact, I'd like to be able to make sure that

- Some users only see a subset of the data available
- Some users only see a subset of the attributes of the documents

I looked at some CouchDB questions related to this, and having a smart proxy seems to be the way to move forward. But is it *really*? Are there any implementations of smart proxies like those out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stumbled across [this, the Sync Gateway](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/couchbase-sync-gateway). That might be exactly what I'm looking for. Would love to hear if there are other solutions though and how to implement one yourself.

Comment: Got this working at some point, but then after some PouchDB changes it no longer seems to work.